# adding subview to main uiview in selector

Tags: xcode, drag-and-drop, addsubview

I'm working on drag and drop app, when the user drop an image, I want to make copy from it in the drapped point, and then the original one returns to it initial point. 
I decided to add uiimageview to my viewcontroller after performing touchesEnded,

I have drag view class containing the method :

```
 - (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

CGPoint activePoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
UIImageView *myimage;
myimage.image = self.image;
myimage.center = activePoint;


ViewController *cview ;
cview = [[ViewController alloc]init];
[cview getpoint: myimage];

}
```

Now in the view controller , this is the getpoint selector :

```
-(void) getpoint : (UIImageView *) mine{
UIImageView *newimage;
newimage = mine;
[self.view addSubview:newimage];


NSLog(@" in getpoint");

}
```

when I drop the object, this error appears :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

but when I remove addsubview statement , the NSlog is going right

any solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually allocating memory for your UIImageViews. This code is suspect:

```
CGPoint activePoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
UIImageView *myimage;
myimage.image = self.image;
myimage.center = activePoint;
```

You need to alloc/init your image view

```
CGPoint activePoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
UIImageView *myimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
myimage.image = self.image;
myimage.center = activePoint;
```

where the `rect` variable holds the rectangle dimensions of the image view you're wanting to add to the hierarchy. You cannot add a nil object to an NSArray. So, since the UIImageView is nil, this call will fail:

```
[self.view addSubview:newimage];
```

Comment: Did you provide a CGRect with an appropriate size to your UIImageView initWithFrame:? Are you sure the image you're passing it is not nil? Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say "it did not work"?